# pointers to objects being created

Tags: c++, pointers, object, infinite-loop

Do not provide an answer that contains vector!

I have a very poor understanding of pointers and every tutorial I research only confuses me more.

Currently my program can take a command which is 'insert'. It will then read strings for a name, url and comment, a double for the length and an int for the rating. It will then make an object.

What I need to do is create a pointer and pass it as an argument to make a list of pointers to the object while using functions from a different class.

How do I:

create the pointer to the object that is being created in main?

pass the pointer to the object being created as an argument into functions that are created and defined in the vlist class?

Here is my code

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "vlist.h"
using namespace std;
#include "video.h"

int main(){
    string command;
    string comment, url, name; // first three getlines 
    double length; // The length for the movie
    int rating; 

     while (getline(cin,command)){
     if (command == "insert"){
        getline(cin, name);
        getline(cin, url);
        getline(cin, comment);
        cin >> length; 
        cin >> rating;
        cin.ignore(); 

        //Video *vid 
        Video = new Video(name, url, comment, length, rating); 

        List list;
        list.insert(); 
     }}
    return 0;
 }
```

video.h

```
#ifndef VIDEO_H
#define VIDEO_H
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Video{

  public:  
    Video(string name, string url, string comment,
                double length, int rating);
    void print();
  private:
    string m_comment; 
    string m_url; 
    string m_name; 
    double m_length;
    int m_rating;
};
void list_length(Video *video[], int num_vids);
#endif
```

video.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "video.h"
using namespace std;

Video :: Video (string name, string url, string comment,
                double length, int rating){
  m_comment = comment;
  m_url = url;
  m_name = name; 
  m_length = length;
  m_rating = rating;
}
void Video :: print (){
  cout << m_name << ", " << m_url << ", " << m_comment << ", "
    << m_length << ", ";
for(int count = 0; count < m_rating; ++count){
    cout << "*";
    }
cout << endl;
}
```

vlist.h

```
#ifndef VLIST_H
#define VLIST_H
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

 class List{
     public:
        List();
        void insert (Video *video);   
     private:
        class Node{
            public:
                Node(string name, string url, string comment,
                        double length, int rating, Node *next){
                    m_name = name;
                    m_url = url;
                    m_comment = comment;
                    m_length = length;
                    m_rating = rating;
                    m_next = next;
                    }
            string m_name, m_url, m_comment;
            double m_length;
            int m_rating;
            Node *m_next;
            };
            Node *m_head;
};
#endif
```

vlist.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "vlist.h"
using namespace std;
List :: List (){
    m_head = NULL;
}
void List :: insert(Video *video){

    m_head = new Node (name, url, comment, length, rating, m_head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have confused what `Node` is.  You've expressed that you want to store the original pointer like this (notice some rearrangement -- omitted irrelevant stuff to make it clearer):

```
List list;
while( ... )
{
    if( ... )
    {
        Video video = new Video( name, url, comment, length, rating ); 
        list.insert( video ); 
    }
}
```

To make this suit your obvious intentions, your `Node` class should store a `Video` pointer instead of duplicating information from the `Video` class:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node( Video *video, Node *next )
        : m_video( video )
        , m_next( next )
    {
    }

    Video *m_video;
    Node *m_next;
};
```

This makes the list insertion as easy as this:

```
void List::insert( Video *video )
{
    m_head = new Node( video, m_head );
}
```

Now you could add something simple to your list like a `print` function:

```
void List::print()
{
    for( Node *node = m_head; node != nullptr; node = node->m_next )
    {
        Video *video = node->m_video;
        if( video != nullptr )
        {
            video->print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean I tried that and I might have the wrong idea of what you are saying.

Comment: Which part do you not understand?  Which part did you try?